# How to create an algorithm that will continue running an algorithm until success in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, bin-packing

I have a package (https://github.com/skjolber/3d-bin-container-packing/) that will pack items into a container for me. However, if there are too many items for example a quantity of 1000 shirts, and only 500  fit in the biggest container we have, it won't try to pack the remaining 500 the result simply returns null and does not try to combine the containers available.

I am tackling a bin-packing-problem. Note that this doesn't need to be an exact solution as we are just putting together a cost calculator for freight. I stumbled upon a package that handles most of the problem. Basically I have 5 containers that are usable. The API receives a request with products and I gather the dimensions and pack them. My initial thought was to check if the pack was successful and if it was then add it to the List packingResults object so that I have a list. But the way this package is set up I suspect that it will not work without losing integrity of the products.

Here is the service constructor

```
public PackingService(List<Product> products) 
{
    containers = SetContainers();
    this.packer = new LargestAreaFitFirstPackager(containers);
    this.products = products;
    PrepareProductsToPack(products);
}
```

the actual packingMethod

```
public List<Container> PackItems()
{
    packedResultContainers = new ArrayList<Container>();
    Container results =  packer.pack(productsToPack);
    return this.packedResultContainers;
}
```

and finally, here is me taking my list of Product entitys and preparing them for the packing algorithm.

```
    productsToPack = new ArrayList<BoxItem>();
    for(Product product : products)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < product.getQuantity(); i++)
        {
            productsToPack.add(new BoxItem(new Box(product.getSku(),
                                                    product.getProductDimensions().getRoundedWidth(),
                                                    product.getProductDimensions().getRoundedDepth(),
                                                    product.getProductDimensions().getRoundedHeight(),
                                                    product.getProductDimensions().getRoundedWeight())));
        }
    }
```

The reason I am confused is because if the inital request fails to pack, then I would need to break apart my List into ,2,3,4 depending on how many items there are and there would be no way for me to know how many lists i need to have.

Can anyone provide some insight on how I can adjust my algorithm to handle this?

I should also state that the reason I am doing it this way, is that once I have my list of results, I make making a UPS Api request to gather shipping methods and their rates.

I am updating my answer for future users, this is how I solved the bin-packing-problem

```
public ArrayList<Container> PackItems()
{
    this.packingResults = new ArrayList<Container>();
    productSetsToPack = chopped(productsToPack, getInitBoxCount(productsToPack));
    int hashMapId = 0;
    for(int i = productSetsToPack.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ArrayList<BoxItem> itemsToPack = productSetsToPack.get(i);
        productSetsMap.put(hashMapId, itemsToPack);
        pack(itemsToPack, hashMapId, 5); //pack largest sized boxs
        ++hashMapId;
    }; 

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Container> entry : packedContainerMap.entrySet()) {
        int containerKey = entry.getKey();
        Container packedContainer = entry.getValue();
        int smallestBoxSize = getSmallestBox(productSetsMap.get(containerKey), Integer.parseInt(packedContainer.getName()));
        packingResults.add(pack(productSetsMap.get(containerKey), smallestBoxSize));
        // ...
    }
    return packingResults;
}
```

Comment: I'm the author of the linked github project, and I was expecting this to work as-is. There has been a few releases since this post, do you mind 'trying again', and if no multi-box result, posting a (failing) unit test on the issue tracker of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boo,
What you want is very possible. It will be quite an undertaking, especially if you have 5 different package sizes. I would suggest using recursion.

create a method that finds the smallest number of the largest packages that your order can fit into. lets say it fits into 4 large boxes. then take each large box and attempt to pack it into smaller boxes. the runs would look something like where box 5 is the biggest box and box 1 is the smallest box.

```
box5 - box5 - box5- box5
box5 - box5 - box5- box4
box5 - box5 - box5- box3
box5 - box5 - box5- box2
box5 - box5 - box5- box1
```

that run would fit into 3 large boxes and 1 small box.

The code to find the largest box would probably be a while loop like such

```
int boxCount = getInitBoxCount(products);

public int getInitBoxCount(ArrayList<BoxItems> items)
{
    if(productsFit(products,sizeLarge) == null)
    {
        ArrayList<BoxItems> temp1 = new ArrayList<BoxItems>();
        ArrayList<BoxItems> temp2 = new ArrayList<BoxItems>();

        for(int x = 0; x < items.length ; x++)
        {
           if(x > items.length/2)
           {
               temp1.add(items.get(x)) 
           }
           else
           {
               temp2.add(items.get(x))
           }
        }
        return getInitBoxCount(temp1) + getInitBoxCount(temp2);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This will continually split your list of BoxItems in half until it fits into the number of boxes

so now we have determined a shipping arrangement that will work but also probably have lots of extra space.

The next 2 steps would be to create a recursive way to trim down the box size such as

```
// 5 is the largest

public int getSmallestBox(int boxsize,ArrayList<BoxItems> items)
{
    if(productsFit(boxsize -1)!= null)
    {
        return getSmallestBox(boxsize -1, items)
    }
    else
        return boxsize;
}
```

And that will get the smallest box that we can fit the items into. The last thing you need to check for is combining boxes. you may find that you have 4 small boxes and you could combine those into 2 medium boxes. after you can combine and shrink boxes then you sould be able to monitor the results after each run. so the overall program flow would look like this in rough pseudo code.

```
Container[getInitBoxCount()] shipments //create an array of containers with the size of the inital box count 

for(Container c : shipments)
{
    c = new LargeContainer();
}


Container[] check; //create new objects into the check array. dont set one array = to anoter

do
{
    check = shipments //create new objects into the check array. dont set one array = to anoter
    for(Container c: shipments)
        getSmallestBox(5, c);
    combineBoxes(shipments);
}
while(check == shipments)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain recursion. It makes sense, however I am little confused on a couple concepts you have in your answer. `check = shipments` what is the purpose of this and doesn't your comment say not to do this? I modified `Container[]` to an `ArrayList<Container>` as it has some useful static methods i can call on it. and instead of creating a new LargeContainer I simply add one to the array list.

Comment: @boo first off. I am sorry that I dont understand the api that you are using and it made my code a bit ambiguous. what i meant by check = shipments is to create a clone of shipments and set it equal to check. I believe that ArrayList's may have a clone() method that will accomplish this. You will also have to fight with the check == shipments what you are trying to compare there is if the ArrayLists have the same size and number of containers

Comment: This may be another question, but in `getInitBoxCount()` im returning an int right, but as of right now it doesn't keep track of what products are in the container. I thought of adding an `arraylist<arraylist<boxitem>>` but if i do that, then every time im going to duplicate the items that were packed if it fails. Do i need to make a new object, and remove items from the parameter array list?

Comment: @caleb_baker  See updated question for the results of your help. Thank again.

Answer (score 0):

See if Spring retry can be of any use.
To have retrial and different logic in the method where you doubt you will not get your first list and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't this simply retry the same code over and over again? If the packing "failed" (it doesnt throw exception but instead just returns null)  then I would need to say split my list of products into a second list of products, then pack both, if both fail then try 3, and this seems like it could in theory never end, so I would need to somehow dynamically create a new object per failed attempt. Is that even possible?

Comment: You can have called different method on failure with @Recover

Answer (score 0):

You could generate all possible subsets of your collection of Items, then iterate over those in sorted order (starting with the largest and decreasing size) until you succeed.

This would of course not scale very well. Id also generate the subsets using list indeces instead of references (Add all items to a list, create a set of numbers from 0 to list.size(), then generate all subsets of this set.)

Answer (score 0):

With the current version, this works:

```
@Test
void testIssue158() {
    List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();
    containers.add(new Container("X",10, 10, 5, 1000));

    List<BoxItem> products = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        products.add(new BoxItem(new Box(Integer.toString(i), 1, 1, 1, 1)));
    }

    LargestAreaFitFirstPackager packager = new LargestAreaFitFirstPackager(containers, false, true, true);
    List<Container> fits = packager.packList(products, 50, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    assertNotNull(fits);
    assertEquals(fits.size(), 2);
}
```

Hopefully that means no custom workaround for multi-container fits!